# Summernote - error when pressing enter key in Bootstrap form

Tags: jquery, summernote

**Error:**

setFieldValue @ onloadwff.js:71

formKeydownListener @ onloadwff.js:71

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create bootstrap 4 form
2. Put summernote instance in form (bootstrap version)
3. Press ENTER key

**Browser version and summernote version**

Browser: Chrome Version 72.0.3626.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Summernote version 0.8.11 (bootstrap version)

**Screenshot**
[image: Image of error]

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Henry3000/4rg32ubL/14/)**

```
<!-- works -->
<div id="summernote"></div>

<!-- triggers ENTER error -->
<form>
  <div id="summernote"></div>
</form>
```

Ideally, I'd like to not have any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The "LastPass: Free Password Manager" extension was changing the form. When I disabled the extension, the error stopped.